# Unable to select the "Talk Device" and go back to present in Minecraft Timecraft

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I am in grade 2 of school.  I am playing [Minecraft Timecraft](https://education.minecraft.net/en-us/resources/hour-code-2021) a on PC running windows 11.

I am in New York-Jazz level 1.
I want to go back in the control center and I need the Talk Device.
But I can't select my Talk Device. It is in my inventory, but I am not able to select it.

[image: mincraft-level-1-image]

Here is what I have tried:

1. checked [minecraft help](https://education.minecraft.net/lessonsupportfiles/6428825307653196-HOC%202021_Minecraft_Educators%20Guide_ENGLISH_FINAL%20QA.pdf)
2. checked [minecraft website](https://education.minecraft.net/en-us/resources/hour-code-2021)

Links

- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSykkOsvUcs)
- [Guide PdF](https://education.minecraft.net/lessonsupportfiles/6428825307653196-HOC%202021_Minecraft_Educators%20Guide_ENGLISH_FINAL%20QA.pdf)
- [Guide Video from minecraft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRNv5dGFaas)
- [Introduction to hourofcode 2021:Timecraft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/hoc-2021-facilitator-training/introduction-hoc-2021)

Comment: Is it that you *can't* select the Talk Device? Or, is it that you *don't know how* to select the Talk Device?

Comment: Thank You @ExpertCoder14 for your question. 
I _don't know_ how to select the talk device.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the selected item in your hotbar pressing numbers between <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, or with the scroll wheel, too.

Then click the "right button" on your mouse, and the Talk Device will activate.

If nothing works then something went wrong, I suggest you close the world (or even the game) and load it back.

Comment: ThankYou @pinkerman for your help.
I will try this solution after school today.